# Enable the Torproject package repository STEP 3 & 4

Tags: tor-install

[image]

I was able to edit the file and add the entries but now im on step 3 and 4 and nothing seems to happen … Step 3

wget -qO- https: // deb.torproject. org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
…
Step 4

#apt update
#apt install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the lines with a `#` symbol - which is a comment till the end of line, so just do it without it and it will be fine. In most of the documents the `#` symbol is used to focus on the fact that it has to be done from the root user, so `sudo -s` will provide you such an access level